# Using a file lock to ensure a PHP Daemon script is only running once

Tags: php, command-line-interface, daemon

I wrote a simple function used to determine if a script is already running, and prevent duplicate processes:

```
class SomeClass{
  public static function processLock($name)
  {
    $lockFile = "/tmp/" . $name;
    $fp       = fopen($lockFile, "w+");

    if ($fp === false)
    {
      echo "Already running.\n";
      exit;
    }
    else
    {
      if ( ! flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB))
      {
        echo "Already running.\n";
        exit;
      }
    }

    return $fp;
  }
}
```

I can then call the function like this at the top of the php script:

Script_A:

```
<?

include_once "/SomeClass.php";

$lock = SomeClass::processLock("script_A_lock");
```

and this works great..... 99% of the time. However, sometimes I'll discover that "script_A" isn't running (it's supposed to always be running).

I then run `lsof /tmp/script_A_lock` to see why "script_A" isn't starting.

The results make no sense! I get something like this:

```
COMMAND    PID     .........     NAME
Script_B   234     .........     script_A_lock
```

An unrelated script "script_B" has somehow stolen the file lock!

So:

1. How is that happening? The word "script_A_lock" ONLY appears in Script_A (I searched the entire project) and Script_A isn't included ANYWHERE.
2. How can I prevent this from happening? Obviously, only Script A should hold the "script_A_lock".

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I usually use for a lock file.  If the file doesn't exist, create it, which indicates the process is executing.  Be sure to unlink it at the end.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
define('LOCK_FILE',__FILE__.'lock');
if (!is_file(LOCK_FILE)) {
    touch(LOCK_FILE);
    echo 'Do stuff'.PHP_EOL;
    unlink(LOCK_FILE);
} else {
    echo 'Lock file found'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

The flock function is intended to support multiple scripts accessing a single file, it's not mean to be used as a lock file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: The `flock` function is meant for both shared and exclusive locks. Just need to use the `LOCK_EX` to make it exclusive. (see the documentation you linked to)

Comment: This method wouldn't work for a Daemon script, because you can't "unlink it at the end". I want the script to run indefinitely. If / when the script ends, it does so unexpectedly.

Comment: Then you could put the **unlink** in a **register_shutdown_function** https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php